# sum multiple columns with sumif function in excel

Tags: excel, function, sum, spreadsheet, sumifs

I would like to sum multiple columns with sumif function column by colum.

For example.
Criteria range is "Column A"
Criteria is "Aplle"
Sum range is "C1:G100"

I dont want to use SUMIF(…) + SUMIF(…) + SUMIF(…) way since I have many columnns.

Thank you

I have tried offset function but didn't work.

Example[image]

Comment: A clear example showing data and expected results would improve this question and reduce the people wasting their effort.

Comment: I added an image. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Good start, now provide the data in a format that people can copy it instead of having to type it out manually.

Comment: as Solar Mike says... [a Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

What about this formula. This sums all cells in all columns which row's A cell equal to condition in cell I1. Result in J1.

This formula is in column H

```
=IF(A1=$I$1,SUM(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":G"&ROW())),0)
```

Result formula in J1.

```
=SUM(H2:H100)
```

[image]

**OR**

```
=SUM(B1:G100*($I$1=A1:A100))
```

where in I1 cell is the value to search to sum.
And instead B1:G100 sequence from B1:B100

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to get sum of columns from the Col A as criteria.

1. Use IF condition to filter the numbers, then wrap it with "SUM" to get the total.

> =SUM(IF(A2:A21="Apple",C2:G21))

2.Use FILTER Output the array of cells from Columns C to G then SUM the arrays.

> =SUM(FILTER(C2:G21,A2:A21="Apple"))

[SS from my Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUmgS.png)

---

**Edit:**

Based on the image, you can freeze the first column then drag to start the SUM from the first column

> =SUM(IF($A$2:$A$25=$B28,$C$2:C25))

dragged to the final column:

> =SUM(IF($A$2:$A$25=$B28,$C$2:G25))

- The above code will match the CRITERIA then will proceed adding the values from $C:C to $C:G

[Freeze column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZhfk.png)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added an image about what I want to have. Your way is giving me total of it. But I need to have them column by column in one cell.

Comment: I've edited the response based on the image you have provided.

Comment: @YavuzSelimKAÇAR "COLUMN by COLUMN in one" cell doesn't make sense

Comment: @ohmyqt- Thank you sooooo much. It worked perfectly. Please have a nice day.